# How to summarize fields into one field?

Tags: ms-access

I am newbie and have a simple question.
In Microsoft Access I have several fields with positive or negative answer.
Can I summarize these fields into one field that contain which fields that have the positive answer in a query?

Example

```
Field1 : positive
Field2 : negative
Field3 : negative
Field4 : positive

Newfield : Field1, Field4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the output from the query below with `id` and `Field1` through `Field4` stored in a table named *YourTable*.

```
id Field1   Field2   Field3   Field4   NewField
-- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------------
 1 positive negative negative positive Field1, Field4
 2 negative positive positive negative Field2, Field3
 3 negative negative negative positive Field4
 4 positive negative negative negative Field1
```

```sql
SELECT
    sub.id,
    sub.Field1,
    sub.Field2,
    sub.Field3,
    sub.Field4,
    IIf
        (
            Right(sub.raw_string,2)=', ',
            Left(sub.raw_string, Len(sub.raw_string) -2),
            sub.raw_string
        ) AS NewField
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            y.id,
            y.Field1,
            y.Field2,
            y.Field3,
            y.Field4,
              (IIf(y.Field1='positive','Field1',Null) + ', ')
            & (IIf(y.Field2='positive','Field2',Null) + ', ')
            & (IIf(y.Field3='positive','Field3',Null) + ', ')
            &  IIf(y.Field4='positive','Field4',Null)
                AS raw_string
        FROM YourTable AS y
    ) AS sub;
```

Comment: Thanks HansUp. This was fast and works great. you saved my day. Just wondering, I have about 20 similar fields, will the IIf command work because I read that it has a limitations regarding the number of commands or its execution time. or do I have to do an alternative. Thanks again

Comment: I think there is a limit for nested `IIf` expressions, but that query doesn't nest them so the limit doesn't apply.  It should still work when extended to 20 fields, but I have no idea whether it will be fast enough for you.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now, I will try it